# Surface area of earth not covered by satellite revolving around the earth orbit

Tags: geometry, physics

A remote sensing satellite is revolving in an orbit of radius x over the equator of earth . Find the area on earth surface in which satelllite can not send message?

Radius of earth R, equitorial distance of satellite is x.

I arrived at answer of $4\pi R^2 [1- {(x-R)\over 2x}]$. However the book answer is $4\pi R^2 [1- {\sqrt{x^2-R^2}\over x}]$. Help me out here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You should show your work.  How you got your answer.  Then maybe we can find your mistake.  Did you start with this: what is the highest latitude that the satellite can see?

Comment: You need to find a line that passes through the tangential point on a sphere and also passes through a point x units away from the surface of the sphere. Since it is an equatorial orbit, it is a good idea to find this tangent as a point of latitude as a previous comment suggested.